# Как вызвать значение словаря в jinja2 по соответствию ключа переменной?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу сценарий для ansible. Через extra-args задаю переменную *os=w*.

Имею словарь *dict_of_os*, в котором одна из строк:

*w: windows 10*

Хочу сделать сделать такое сообщение на вывод:

*"Сейчас будет установлена операционная система {{ dict_of_os.[os].value }}"*

Но явно не понимаю, как устроен синтаксис jinja и как получить нужный результат

Comment: `{{ dict_of_os[os] }}`

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили!